# Is it possible to Import * in typescript

Tags: import, typescript

Is it possible to import all of exported classes and function in a `.ts` file at one using `*` something like `import * from './myModule';`

I don't want `import * as me from './myModule';` and then call the functions like `me.myFunc`

I want something like python `from myModule import *`

Comment: FWIW its considered bad practice in python as well

Comment: @basarat yeah but sometimes it's easier to do it this way

Comment: it hurts discoverability / reviewability 

Comment: @basarat ok! i'll keep that in mind, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. You either have to specifiy what you want to import like this:

```
import {SomeClass, SomeInterface} from './someModule';
```

or import it into a variable and call it from there like you already stated:

```
import * as someModule from './someModule';
```

You can however import a module without assigning a variable to it, if you don't need its functionality in your module. This could be useful, if it just sets up some global state:

```
import './someModule';
```

Comment: Are you sure the last line works? the import is fine but I still get an error when I try to use classes from that module

Comment: Yes, like I wrote - you can't use the classes and stuff inside :)

Comment: then what is the benefit of importing like this?

Comment: Did you read my answer or did you just try the code out? Like I wrote: it's useful, if it's just some code, that directly executes and maybe sets some global variables or whatever. You can not use the classes/interfaces or anything it exports, though.